# PCB Mount Switch to Breadboard Adapter

Tags: pcb, switches, breadboard, adapter, prototyping

I'm currently working on implementing [this switch](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/979-6425.0101) in my project (PCB Mounted).
[image]

I'd like to move to the part of my project where I can implement a looks-like, works-like prototype, but I'm currently still using a breadboard.

Does anyone know of how I can adapt the switch for breadboard use, until I'm ready to move onto the PCB?

Thanks.

Comment: use some other switch for testing

Comment: Closed. Edited to make site acceptable. Reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datasheet, let's look at this switch. This is the side view to the two pins that come down:

[image]

And this show the view where one pin obscures the other (and a top view which we will ignore). There are also "teeth" that come down into cut-out holes in the PCB to give it stability and helps with reliability, for connections to survive many activations.

[image]

This is a bottom view with green highlights around the two pins, and yellow highlights around the two teeth.

[image]

The best way might be to use two PCB's to make an adapter. The top PCB mates with the switch. And the bottom pcb mates with the breadboard. And the boards fit together sort of like an Arduino hosts its daughter-board.

If you don't want to go through what promises to be "the long way" (because of ordering PCB's), then you might implement something similar in styrofoam and cardboard.

What follows are some thoughts along those lines:

Take a piece of extra thick (or doubled) cardboard, and cover it on both sides with packing tape for extra rigidity -- this can be your "temporary PCB" for your switch, the same way a heavy toroid inductor has its own FR4.

Or if you suspect you may need something fireproof, you could just use a small piece of FR4 the same size as your switch. Either way...

Put double-sided tape on top of that with which to stick the switch down. Poke four wires through, one at each corner, for stability and firm attachment -- I use 1/4 watt through-hole resistor lead because it's nickel plated and just the right thickness. I cut it at a sharp angle to make it extra pointy for ease of insertion.

You don't have to actually use all of the posts electrically -- on switching transformers, I see "dummy" posts all the time. You're trying to both connect it well electrically, but also connect it well physically.

Finally, if it doesn't work out the first time, disassemble and try again, because practice makes perfect, and you'll get it.

Here are some mounting solutions for toroids, having similar needs for strong mounting. (These are for permanent mounting, but we can still learn from them.)

This one has a tiny board. I don't like it much. "Why bother?" comes to mind. Drop this product, and the inductor will likely break a solder joint.

[image]

You can see the black epoxy that holds this one on. A "stage" like this might be 3D-printable:

[image]

As you can see, all kinds of materials are used as a base. I think that's the same plastic out of which they make Legos (which could be made to work, for my kids,  of course).

[image]

The deep container (cup?) gives great rigidity and therefore stability. No torsion at all, probably, after adding the epoxy and the component. And you can glue the whole thing down with silicone to keep it in place, and yet have a little bit of flexibility.

[image]

I might be tempted to use the cup idea, but with a 3.5mm lip, because I think that would fit the switch nicely.

---

All schematic images from datasheet referenced by OP. All toroid images from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/fixed-inductors/71?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGGABxwDsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CtAMyIQKSBhwFiZSmGlxNzNp0g9%2BwsZPBw6chUryESkcgAZmJgLQAmC1H4BXFbfIBWJxN3OxAAFSI%2BIgEAEx0QGDlYrmcwewhdLhBCdgBPVlwuGOwUcXEgA). Search through-hole toroids, sort descending on price.

Comment: A lovely answer ! :-) . Very nice. || Can you add links to the image sources unless they are public domain.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - They are all from Digikey.  Is that good enough?

Comment: SE EE rules require citation of material that is not either self generated or public domain. || Stating in the answer that they are from Digikey with a link would do. || eg "All images from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/eaton-electronics-division/CTX20-2-52M-R/667502) may suffice.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Done.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the switch.

Add wires (see other answers) BUT be careful when soldering not to destroy the switch with heat.

If you want "lookalike" you may want the switch to insert through a thin sheet to hide the breadboard.

Or you may need to trim the bottom of the switch to lower it IF there are protrusions on the bottom that are not needed for breadboard use.

Answer (score 2):

Cut some male-male jumper wire in half and solder the two ends to the switch

Answer (score 2):

You can try standard breadboard wires male/female.
[image]

Or cut a piece of PCB, solder switch and two pins on it.